# Words in word cloud getting overlapped in mobile

Tags: javascript, word-cloud

For some specific word cloud generated on some specific mobiles, words are getting overlapped. I used wordCloud2.js for creating word cloud. Its causing problem only in mobile so not able to debug.

Comment: FYI you can debug mobile applications i Chrome by connecting via e.g. `adb` and the browse to `chrome://inspect`. [Read more here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried that.